# Using Google Mobile Ads SDK v7.4.1 for iOS (GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.4.1) with bitcode for app thinning

Tags: admob, ios9

When linking an iOS 9 app against Google Mobile Ads SDK v7.4.1 for iOS (as a framework) I get this error message:

> GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.4.1/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureIdUtil.o)'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.

What is the right way to overcome what looks like a Catch 22?

- Google does not seem to provide a version with bitcode enabled (or does it?)
- If I disable bitcode for my app I risk Apple rejecting it (or won't I?)

Comment: This is what they suggests: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios9?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

I've meanwhile found this in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html):

> For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide
>   bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include
>   bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.

So turning bitcode off for the iOS app target should be a feasible approach for the time being.

Comment: This post from last week says they are actively working on it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ypBRdg5z0uM

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not allow submissions to the app store using Xcode Betas. So there's no way you could release with bitcode at the moment.

Google might be waiting until iOS9 is out before they release any bitcode enabled libraries to avoid confusion.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5989

Comment: You're right: I was (implicitly) referring to releasing the app with the final version.